# How to make pytesseract to work on Raspberry Pi 5?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm having issues with `pytesseract` on my raspberry pi 5.

Running the program kept saying

```
An error occurred on visual studio code: <path_to_pytesseract_executable> is not 
installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more info.
```

(all other libraries worked just fine, following the same installation process)

I successfully installed all packages needed `sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`, `pip install pytesseract`. I also updated them (they were already up to date).

Doing `pip` list and `pip` show `pytesseract`, and it indicated me that the library was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm having issues with pytesseract on my raspberry pi 5

It is working right now on Raspberry Pi 4 and 5.

The merely problem is `python3-pip` instead of `python-pip`.

Firstly, install this ...`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Then secondly...`sudo pip install pytesseract`.

Then run the script.

screenshot:

[image]